# Where to save the "python manage.py build_solr_schema" output between "managed-schema" and "solrconfig.xml"?

Tags: solr, django-haystack

Where to save the output of `python manage.py build_solr_schema > *` ?

Is it `managed-schema` or `solrconfig.xml` while using **django-haystack** with **Solr 8.6.2** ?

Comment: it should be to the managed-schema

Comment: See here for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65879529/9913319

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the managed schema or schema.xml.

Please refer the below code.

```
python manage.py build_solr_schema > schema.xml
```

Additionaly you can copy the file at required folder with below.

```
sudo cp schema.xml /usr/share/solr/conf/schema.xml
```

Comment: Is it for Solr 8.* ?

Comment: its irrespective of the version...schema related changes are saved to solr.xml or to managed schema file